# Insert div after closest sibling with specified class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I have code like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And when I click on div with class `prcolor`, I want to insert new div after closest sibling with class `visible-xs`.

I tried `$.next('.visible-xs')`, `$.closest('.visible-xs')`, `$.siblings('.visible-xs')`, `$.nextAll('.visible-xs')`, but as I read, the selector is accepted only if function can't found element in DOM.

```
$('.prcolor').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.visible-xs').after('<div>Inserted div</div>');
});
```

But this is doing nothing and the div is not inserted after. Where am I wrong?

Example of expected after clicking on first `.prcolor`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
    <div>Inserted div</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 prcolor">Test</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/legionar/5joer6ot/1/)

Thanks.

Comment: Please create a snippet.

Comment: closest is a PARENT

Comment: `$.fn.closest` find the parents(ancestry) of the selector

Comment: `closest sibling` i guess you mean nearest one but still unclear what you are expecting. Is it the nearest following one or even a previous sibling?! Maybe you want: `$(this).nextAll('.visible-xs').first().after('<div>Test</div>');`

Comment: Updated expected result.

Comment: Created a snippet for you. Your JSFiddle did not even use jQuery

Comment: So is it what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/eujv05vy/ ???

Comment: @A.Wolff post your comment so I can vote it up

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, it looks like. Add it as an answer.

Comment: This answer doesn't go "up" the DOM tree, only down.. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, only down closest with the class `.visible-xs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match nearest **following** sibling with specific class, you can use [$.fn.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) chained with [$.fn.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/). e.g:

```
$('.prcolor').on('click', function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.visible-xs').first().after('<div>INSERTED</div>');
});
```

Comment: just out of curiosity: is there also a way to look in both direction?

Comment: @HoangVu You'd have to compare nearest previous, nearest next and current clicked element indexes to get the 'nearest' one